# Error while creating interface in onAttach method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, interface

I am getting error "Incompatible types" in the onAttach method. Im trying to create interface here but don't know why this is happening i think i did it the right way. And also when i calls "createMeme" method it gives me error that "con not resolve this method" while this method i public. Any confusion in understanding my question than plz ask, i'm a terrible asker any way. Anyone has any idea ? Thanks in advance :)

```
public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragments
{
private static EditText toptextInput;
private static EditText bottomtextInput;

TopSectionFragment activityCommander;

public interface TopSectionListener
{
    public void createMeme(String topText, String bottomText);
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        activityCommander = (TopSectionListener) activity;//error here
    }catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException (activity.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, this declaration of `onAttach` is deprecated, it should take `Context context` as the parameter. Secondly, show your Activity. Does it implement `TopSetionListener`

Comment: @Andreyua i implemented it. but still it was giving same error. hence i changed type of activityCommander and error removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comments from @Vucko and @Andreyua, I would like to add the following:

```
TopSectionListener activityCommander;
```

instead of

```
TopSectionFragment activityCommander;
```